# Partial least square structural equation modeling

Tags: reference-request, econometrics, causality

The [Partial least square structural equation modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_path_modeling) (PLS-PM, PLS-SEM) method to structural equation modeling allows estimating complex cause-effect relationship models with latent variables. This method seems quite popular in accounting, marketing, and management.

Do you know any good application in economics? Is this method reliable to get causal estimates?